# CoreLocation Location does not update when heading is updating

Tags: ios, core-location

I need to get the position and the heading. Once I run my code, I only get the heading updates, location does not update as it doesn't appear in logs.

If I disable heading updates,I get my location coordinates. 
If heading updates is on I don't get location.
Has anyone had the same sort of problem?

Here's my set up routine and my methods:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.headingFilter = 1;
locationManager.delegate = self;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation//          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{NSString *currentLatitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSLog(@"currentLatitude = %@", currentLatitude);

NSString *currentLongitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
NSLog(@"currentLongitude = %@", currentLongitude);

NSString *currentHorizontalAccuracy = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
NSLog(@"currentHorizontalAccuracy = %@", currentHorizontalAccuracy);

NSString *currentAltitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.altitude];
NSLog(@"currentAltitude = %@", currentAltitude);

NSString *currentVerticalAccuracy = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.verticalAccuracy];
NSLog(@"currentVerticalAccuracy = %@", currentVerticalAccuracy);
}- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration: (CLLocationManager *)manager {
return NO;}


     -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{
CLLocationDirection trueHeading = newHeading.trueHeading;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location has not been updating because the method has been updated in ios 6.0

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
```

This is how the didUpdateLocations should look like, now it takes an array.
[locations lastObject] this is the last know location in the array. From it you can get the coordinates and else.